# function from separate file ,FireBug :SyntaxError document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, firebug

on head the head of the page i include the .js file

```
<script src="ajax.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the button that call the function in html file

```
<button type='button' id="submit" onclick="javascript:Action(2,0,10)" >Search</button>
```

js function

```
function Action(var a,var jump,var number)

var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("textField");
```

when the website lunch firebug show error

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("textField");
```

and when  i am trying to call the function from the website firebug show this message

```
ReferenceError: Action is not defined
Action(2, 0, 10);
```

what is the problem? its becose i am trying to call the document from a different file? if it is how can i fix it?

...
changing the function to this do not solve the problem :

```
function Action(a,jump,number)
```

ajax.js

```
<script>
function Action(a,jump,number)
{
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("textField");
var value = "FirstName="+texts[0].value+"&LastName="+texts[1].value+"&Id="+texts[2].value+"&DateBirth="+texts[3].value+"&CellPhone="+texts[4].value+"&Text="+texts[5].value+"&ImageSource="+texts[6].value;
var insert = "?"+value;
var get = "?Jump="+jump+"&NumberToGet="+number+"&"+value;
if (a == 1){
   loadXMLDoc("get.php"+get,"view");
}else if (a == 0){
   loadXMLDoc("insert.php"+insert,"view");
}
}
```

...
loadXMLDoc() = simple ajax function.

Comment: I don't get an syntax error from the last code. Maybe the error is somewhere before the file, you can only try be removing everything else. Also scripts before that one could cause such an error.

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your Action function by removing the `var` keywords.

```
function Action(a,jump,number)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
function Action(var a,var jump,var number)
```

Not sure why FireBug shows the syntax error for the next line. Have a look at [function statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) for the correct syntax:

```
function action (a, jump, number) {
    var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("textField");
    …
}
```

The lowercased name is not a must, but uppercased ones are usually only used for constants and constructor functions.

Also, you should not use the `javascript:` scheme in event handler attributes. `onclick="action(2,0,10)"` is enough.

Comment: i am getting the same error massage :

Comment: Could you please [show](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13688125/edit) us the whole error message? I don't think it's that unspecific. Also, you might show us a bigger excerpt from your ajax.js file - the reason of syntax error may be long before it is detected.